# Обновление строки на kivy

Tags: python, kivy

как мне сделать чтобы при вводе правильного ответа в нижнюю строку обновлялась верхняя строка. Для ввода цифр внутри программы предусмотрены 9 кнопок P. S Я хочу сделать чтобы программа писала число и когда user введет правильный ответ число обновлялось и так до бесконечности 9*9 = 81 ; 81*81= 6561- это квадраты. Когда я пишу

```
def uupdate_label(self):    
    self.llbl.text = self.fformula
    if self.formula != '0' :
        # if '*' in mas:    
        self.llbl.text  = self.fformula
        self.llbl.text = str(eval(qw))
        self.fformula = ''
```

для обновления верхней строки Компилятор выдает

```
   AttributeError: 'CalculatorApp' object has no attribute 'fformula'
```

self.llbl = Label(text=qw, font_size = 20, size_hint = (1, .15))
bl.add_widget(self.llbl)

```
    self.lbl = Label(text="0", font_size = 50, halign="right", valign="center", 
      size_hint 
        (1.15))

   bl.add_widget( self.lbl )
```

[image: Знать квадраты]

Comment: Ошибка говорит о том что в классе CalculatorApp нет атрибута fformula. У Вас прописана инициализация экземпляра (def __init __...)? если нет то можно в init-е задать стандартное значение атрибутов (в частности атрибута fformula), дабы избежать такие ошибки

Comment: Что значит "Знать квадраты111"? Укажите в заголовке суть вопроса, а не произвольный текст.

Comment: @insolor
Я новичок я не умею менять название

Comment: @Сергей под вопросом есть ссылка "править".